# How to make a string into an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having a `string` like this..

```
food_item => 'Butter Croissant',food_id => '1',quantity => '1',price => '140'
```

I tried **explode** option

But I'm getting an `array` like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => 'food_item' => 'Butter Croissant'
    [1] => 'food_id' => '1'
    [2] => 'quantity' => '1'
    [3] => 'price' => '140'
)
```

But I should need to make it as an `array` like as follows,

```
Array
(
    [food_item] =>  'Butter Croissant'
    [food_id]   =>  '1'
    [quantity]  =>  '1'
    [price]     =>  '140'
)
```

how should I do this,Someone please help me..

Thank you in advance..

Comment: Your first "string" is an array, not a string

Comment: Maybe he has it as a string...

Comment: Maybe, but it is a little confusing

Comment: If you explode the string using ','   the part of string "food_item => 'Butter Croissant' " will considered as a string

Comment: What if food name contains a `,`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***You can do it like below:-***

```
<?php
$string = "food_item => 'Butter Croissant',food_id => '1',quantity => '1',price => '140'"; // original string

$first_array = explode(',',$string); // your first explode with `,`

$final_array = array(); // create a new empty array

foreach($first_array as $arr){ // iterate over previously exploded array
    $data = explode('=>',$arr); // now explode the value again with `=>`
    $final_array[trim($data[0])] = trim($data[1]);  // add it to final array in the form of key=>value pair
}

echo "<pre/>";print_r($final_array);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/609356

Note:- this is easiest stuff to do and to understand also.thanks

Comment: @SuganyaRajasekar  glad to help you

Comment: @ Anant Yes I did it :)

Comment: Care with comma's in your string. I would advice a regex. You have a problem with `$string = "food_item => 'Butter, Croissant'...`

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$str = "food_item => 'Butter Croissant',food_id => '1',quantity => '1',price => '140'";
$mainArray = explode(",",$str);
$newArray = array();
foreach($mainArray as $main) {
  $innerArray = explode("=>",$main);
  $newArray[trim($innerArray[0])] = trim($innerArray[1]);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [food_item] => 'Butter Croissant'
    [food_id] => '1'
    [quantity] => '1'
    [price] => '140'
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer..:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$str = "food_item => 'Butter Croissant',food_id => '1',quantity => '1',price => '140'";
$exploded = array_map('myExplode', explode(',', $str));
$result = [];
foreach ($exploded as $itemPieces) {
    $result[trim($itemPieces[0])] = trim($itemPieces[1]);
}

function myExplode($item) {
    return explode("=>", str_replace("'", '', $item));
}

var_dump($result);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
array (size=4)
  'food_item' => string 'Butter Croissant' (length=16)
  'food_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'quantity' => string '1' (length=1)
  'price' => string '140' (length=3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `preg_split` in combination with `foreach` Loop for that like so:

```
    <?php
        $strArray       = "food_item => 'Butter Croissant',food_id => '1',quantity => '1',price => '140'";
        $arrKVPairs     = preg_split("#,\s?#", $strArray);
        $arrStrToArray  = array();

        foreach($arrKVPairs as $ikey=>$strData){
            $arrKeyVal      = preg_split("#\s?\=>\s?#", trim($strData, "'"));
            if(count($arrKeyVal) == 2){
                list($key, $val)        = $arrKeyVal;
                $arrStrToArray[$key]    = trim($val, "'");
            }
        }
        var_dump($arrStrToArray);
        // PRODUCES::

        array (size=4)
          'food_item' => string 'Butter Croissant' (length=16)
          'food_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'quantity' => string '1' (length=1)
          'price' => string '140' (length=3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since we got answers I wanted to post different solution (given string is much like parameters string that can be parsed in array or in vars by [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) function):

```
$string = "food_item => 'Butter Croissant',food_id => '1',quantity => '1',price => '140'";

$paramString = str_replace([',', " => ", "'"], ['&', '=', ''], $string);

parse_str($paramString, $data);
```

Now we got data as needed, and code looks a bit cleaner